# Too many indexers python iloc

Tags: python, pandas, neural-network

I'm trying to program a Feedforward Neural Network which has 41 input features.
In order to feed  all features in batches, I use the following method:

```
batch_x,batch_y=feature.iloc[i, :].values.tolist(),target.iloc[i, :].values.tolist()
```

This results in  the following error:

** IndexingError: Too many indexers**

I have 41 features which need to be fed in the neural network.
Please guide me an alternate way or help me to improvise.
My Neural network session is Defined as follow

```html
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(logs_path,graph=tf.get_default_graph())
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        batch_count=int(len(feature)/batch_size)
        for i in range(batch_count):

            
            batch_x,batch_y=feature.iloc[i, :].values.tolist(),target.iloc[i, :].values.tolist()

            _,summary = sess.run([train_step,summary_op],
                                 {X:batch_x,Y:batch_y,learning_rate:0.001}
                                )
```

Comment: Can you share the structure of the feature df ? e.g. feature.head(5)